# How to slow down just one frame of a CCAnimation?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I have a sprite of a character punching which is a cool fast punch effect.

the point is, when there is a collision (I've done this part already) I want the 1 frame of the CCAnimation to take 2x than usual. I want to avoid creating a new CCAnimation with an extra frame just to solve this.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create two animations played in sequence:

- punch start (ends in "cool" punch frame)
- punch end

So at a minimum you've got to split the animation in two (start, end). Then you'd create a CCSequence with the start animation, a waitForDelay action, and the end animation.

You create this sequence anew every time you play the punch animation, or you have a copy of both. Either way you can influence how long the last frame of the start animation is shown by changing the time for the delay action.

Comment: I need to sit and read this answer several times to get it :)

Comment: Or just create two CCAnimation, after all you only need to create one as usual, then another one that has the "cool punch" frame added multiple times to make it appear to play longer. A CCAnimation consumes very little memory.

Comment: interesting thing is, when I add another of the same frame, I got more than 1 collision hit...not sure how I am going to solve this